# Return this in cfc component, cfdumpinitiated false

Tags: coldfusion, components, this

I've never seen this before I have a component in a cfc file and I use

`<cfset request = CreateObject("component","path/to/component") />`

When I set request to the above or:

`<cfset request = CreateObject("component","path/to/component").init() />` or

`<cfset request = CreateObject("component","path/to/component").from_request() />`

etc I always get a struct with a single item that is the equivilant of

`{cfdumpinited = false}`

I've never see this before. The `from_request` method reuturns `init` and `init` returns `this`.

When I `<cfdump this>` right before the `<cfreturn this>` I get the full object output on the screen. But when I `<cfdump request>` I get the struct stated above. Anyone know what causes Coldfusion to return this type of struct. I can post the entire cfc but I don't think that will help as I stated, right before the return I can output `this` and it is the entire object/component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`request` is a scope in ColdFusion, therefore you should use another variable name.

Comment: wow........ duh. Somedays you just can't see the forest for the trees. I'm converting a PHP application to CF and didn't notice that one. Geeze.